# using ansible set_fact module to define persistent facts?

Tags: ansible

I want to define a playbook which establishes facts about my hosts that can be used in other plays.  The set_fact module claims to be able to do this ... http://docs.ansible.com/set_fact_module.html -- however it's not working ...  The facts I define are available after the call to set_fact within a run of the play-book -- I would then expect to be able to use ansible all -m setup and see the fact defined somewhere within the facts gathered for each host ...

I tried looking into the code for the set_fact module -- but all I find is documentation string ... https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/19b328c4df2157b6c0191e9144236643ce2be890/utilities/logic/set_fact.py

Comment: Good question and I did not know `set_fact` _should_ work persistent. I tried to find the actual code, only found a reference that `set_fact` is an action plugin but was unable find the action plugins now that everything is split up in 3 repos. I found [this thread from the mailing list](http://grokbase.com/p/gg/ansible-devel/149rhwqtxy/persistent-set-fact) which mentions an undocumented `persistent` parameter. Maybe play with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the set_fact module only sets facts available during a run.  For persistent facts, you'll need to either:

> --Static--
>
> - define them in one of the following:
>
>   - vars/
>   - group_vars/
>   - host_vars/
>
> --Dynamic--
>
> - Assign them to hosts using your language of choice via Ansible's Dynamic Inventory:
>
>   - http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html
>   - http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_inventory.html

The latter is what I usually choose to do, as it is quite simple to set up, and the facts are always available on all hosts, even if you are doing something like:

> - getting all the facts for all the hosts while connected to a nagios host in order to generate its configuration files.

Comment: Indeed I should've come back to this question to update after learning the answer (the documentation for the set_fact module is confusing to newbies -- at least it confused me when I was first starting with ansible).  The variables defined via set_fact only survive between plays _within the same playbook run_.

Comment: set_fact can now be used to cache variables and persist them between executions.  See http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#fact-caching and http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/set_fact_module.html

Comment: yes, *cacheable* parameter added after ansible 2.4 in set_fact module

Answer (score 2):

If a remotely managed system has an /etc/ansible/facts.d directory, any files in this directory ending in .fact, can be JSON, INI, or executable files returning JSON, and these can supply local facts in Ansible, since 1.3. An alternate directory can be specified using the fact_path play directive.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#local-facts-facts-d

Answer (score 1):

What version of Ansible are you using?  As of version 1.8, there is a built-in [fact caching capability](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#fact-caching), but it's disabled by default. You would need to enable it within your ansible.cfg file, and you also need to have a redis server running since that's what actually caches the facts.

Comment: I'm using ansible 1.8.4.  I understood the documentation of the set_fact module quite differently ...  I thought it was doing something more like creating some state on the host executing the task to store a fact value -- something akin to creating or updating a file within /etc/facts.d/ which would capture the parameters passed to set_fact.  Thats seems like the natural interpretation of 'These variables will survive between plays' to me ...

Comment: I'm actually not trying to use facts from remote nodes -- but rather I'm trying to capture and freeze a piece of state about a host (its ssh host public key) so that I can detect if that changes and if it has, I want to generate an error.  My goal is to define a workflow so that I can easily collect all ssh host public keys from nodes added to my infrastructure, verify and sign off on them, and then easily detect if any of them change from the centrally approved value

Comment: I will go about this a little differently -- 

(1) get value of validated copy of remote host's public hostkey for ansible_hostname from control machine into a variable using the file 'lookup' mechanism
(2) get value of /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub using shell: cat and register
(3) generate error if mismatch unless explicitly overridden

Thanks for the help.  Would appreciate any suggestions if this sounds like a bad approach.

Comment: I'm on ansible 1.9.1 and facts caching persists only facts gathered by ansible. I can't make it persist any of user-defined facts and/or variables. Am I missing any trick?

Comment: That seems correct.  The cached facts only contain the facts from "gathering facts", i.e. the setup module.  See my answer below on possible solutions.